# Can data contained in a push notification be shown in a textview display, on another view?

Tags: android

```
     @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final String str=intent.getStringExtra("str");
        Log.v("debugging", str);

NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(Myservice.this, Display.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(Myservice.this, 0, i, 0);
Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,str, System.currentTimeMillis());
n.setLatestEventInfo(Myservice.this,"New message for you: ", str, pi);
nm.notify(1,n);
            }
```

Now I want to display the "str" ie data into a textview into another xml. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Myservice.this, Display.class);
i.putExtras("str_key", str);
```

And in `Display Activity` get `str` like this :

```
String strValue = getIntent.getExtras().getString("str_key");
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is creating Activity which will open after user clicks on notification's item.